# json-c json_object_to_json_string() equivalent api in jansson library

Tags: json, json-c, jansson

In the Current code i'm using json-c. i'm migrating to jansson.
need an equivalent api in jansson which converts the json_object_to_json_string. 
i found one but it needs a json string object otherwise it is returning null.

const char *json_string_value(const json_t *string)  - not working

but my input is a `JSON` object not a `JSON` string

### sample:

```
json_object *jobj = json_object_new_object();

....

const char *final_string = json_object_to_json_string(jobj);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was in your position just recently, I believe the function you are looking for is:

> `char *json_dumps(const json_t *json, size_t flags)`
>
> Returns the JSON representation of json as a string, or NULL on error. flags is described above. The return value must be freed by the caller using free().

https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.8/apiref.html#c.json_dumps